# Save edited data in html rows

Tags: jquery

I have the following code in which I am able to edit the context in rows, and each row contains a save button. When I edit and save the context it is working fine, but when I try to edit and don't save it and try to edit the other rows, the context which I edited is getting saved without clicking the save button. How do I revert to the original value?

```
$("#tableid").on("click", "tr", function ()
{
    $(this).find(".btnsave").attr("disabled", false);
    $(".btnsave").click(function () {
        $("#tableidtd").each(function ()
        {
            if ($(this).hasClass("editclass"))
            {
                $(this).parents('tr').css("background-color", "white");
                $(this).html($(this).find('input').val());
                $(this).removeClass("editclass");
                $(".btnsave").attr("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    });
    $("#tableid td").each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("editclass")) {
            $(this).parents('tr').css("background-color", "white");
            $(this).html($(this).find('input').val());
            $(this).removeClass("editclass");
        }
    });
    $(this).find('td:not(:first-child, :last-child)').each(function ()
    {
        var oldcontent= $(this).text();
        if (oldcontent!= " ")
        {
            $(this).parents('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
            $(this).addClass("editclass");
            $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + oldcontent+ "'/>");
            $(this).children().first().focus();
            $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e)
            {
                if (e.which == 13)
                {
                    $(this).parents('tr').css('background-color', 'white');
                    var newtext= $(this).val();
                    $(this).parent().text(newtext);
                    $(this).removeClass("editclass");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $(this).children().first().blur(function () {
        $(this).parent().text(oldcontent);
        $(this).removeClass("editclass");
    });
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net)

Comment: @Taleeb http://jsfiddle.net/tom_boy/zqc5Le4o/ here is my fiddle but its not wrking.may be u will get an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood from your question - you need to keep backup of the row's (`tr`) data which can be used to restore the value as and when required. In the following example I've used an array to store the backup

```
arrBackupData = [];
$("#tableid").on("click", "td", function () {
    if ($(this).find('.btnsave').length > 0) {
        return;
    }
    var tRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    $(tRow).find(".btnsave").attr("disabled", false);

    $("#tableid td.editclass").each(function () {
        $(this).parents('tr').css("background-color", "white");
        if (arrBackupData.length > 0) {
            $(this).html(arrBackupData.shift());
        } else {
            $(this).html($(this).find("input").val());
        }
        $(this).removeClass("editclass");
    });
    arrBackupData = [];

    $(tRow).find('td:not(:first-child, :last-child)').each(function () {
        var oldcontent = $(this).text();
        if (oldcontent != " ") {
            arrBackupData.push(oldcontent);
            $(this).parents('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
            $(this).addClass("editclass");
            $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + oldcontent + "'/>");
            $(this).children().first().focus();

            $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    $(this).parents('tr').css('background-color', 'white');
                    var newtext = $(this).val();
                    $(this).parent().text(newtext);
                    $(this).removeClass("editclass");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $(tRow).children().first().blur(function () {
        $(this).parent().text(oldcontent);
        $(this).removeClass("editclass");
    });
    return false;
});

$(".btnsave").click(function () {

    $("#tableid td.editclass").each(function () {

        $(this).parents('tr').css("background-color", "white");
        $(this).html($(this).find('input').val());
        $(this).removeClass("editclass");
        $(".btnsave").attr("disabled", true);

    });
});
```

See updated jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/zqc5Le4o/2/)

Comment: my problem was if i edit the value and click on save button it should be saved..if i edit the  first td and go to another row and  the first edited row should get back the old value

Comment: @learner. I've updated the answer. See updated jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/zqc5Le4o/2/)

Comment: thank you.actually the previous one was also working.+1 for you.Thanks man :) @Taleeb